# jQuery Animate not working

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using jQuery to move some elements on screen, however the animate function is not working (or my CSS definition is hindering it, more like..).
For instance, I believe this animate element id foobar to a given position..

```
$('#foobar').animate({ top: '0px', left: '200px' });
```

I've a jsfiddle example here: [have a play](http://jsfiddle.net/upNSd/1/)

As far as I am aware, I should be able to place absolute positioned elements (class menuButton in the example) so long as they are inside a relative positioned div (ScreenDesign in the example). However I cannot get this to work.

Thanks :)

Comment: I'm not sure about your issue but i noticed that u haven't included jquery at the example. with this fiddle the stuff is "moving" http://jsfiddle.net/upNSd/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jsFiddle isn't working because [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) isn't included (only [MooTools](http://mootools.net/), a different library, is included by default).

To include jQuery, choose it from the "framework" tab:

[image]

Here's a fixed version: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/upNSd/).

Comment: Marked as answer as yours was quickest off the mark, and it does fix the issue in jFiddle (the first time I've used it tbh). I'm still getting the original issue in my complete project however, which does include jquery 1.8.1 (I can see it loaded in firebug) so for the original issue I'm still no further. err...

Comment: @Fetchezlavache Can you post your full HTML on [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com) or similar?

Comment: ok.. not quite sure what to say. Pasted *all* the output in jsfiddle again and it's working there as well. http://jsfiddle.net/7AszQ/

Comment: OK, it would seem the id's I'm trying to animate do not reflect the HTML. Looks like i'll have to add another question about this, or just go to the pub...

Answer (score 1):

You just forgot to reference jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/upNSd/2/

To debug similar problems, you should inspect the javascript console (F12 in both Chrome and  FireBug). For your fiddle it states:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'animate' of null

Comment: Position `animation` doesn't have any jQuery UI dependencies.

Comment: +1 @Abody97 No jQuery UI dependencies but certainly jQuery dependencies. :) BTW F12 on PC no Mac

Comment: @anonymousdownvotingislame His answer used to say "You forgot to reference jQuery and jQuery UI", that's what I was referring to. Apparently edit history isn't visible for some reason.

Comment: @Abody97 Understood. Maybe if you edit it within a minute it doesn't count revisions. Good point. Animating background colors does need the UI reference.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your animation in the jQuery ready function, ensuring the DOM is fully loaded.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(onready);

  function onready
  {
    jQuery('#foobar').animate({ top: '0px', left: '200px' });

  }
```

Also, using 'jQuery' as opposed to the doller sign will ensure no conflict with any over js library :-)

Comment: this is not necessary for jsfiddle, which wraps your scripts with $(window).load automatically